# Telegram API Client receive message

Tags: telegram

I have problems with telegram's api in c#. I search any solutions how to recevie message from Telegram using API. I found only library for Telegram BOT(send message etc.), but I need only recevie message from one user. There is option "Get.Message" in Telegram Api, but I can't find simply library to use this option.

Answer (score 2):

using the telegram client api you can get updates automatically from telegram when a message is received. You simply need to handle the response once the session is created and a connection is made

Just in case you don't want realtime updates, you can use messages.GetHistory and supply the number of messages you'd like to retrieve. You need to provide the chat ID and access hash which you can get from contactsResolveUsername

[enter link description here](https://core.telegram.org/api/updates)